# Event handlers on nested elements don't work with Vue 3.3 and Cypress

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, cypress

I'm experiencing a really weird issue when running Cypress, which only happens after upgrading from Vue 3.2 to 3.3. The issue does not occur when running the app, only when using Cypress. So I have no idea if the issue is related to Cypress, or to Vue.

Basically, the issue comes down to this:

```
<div @click="console.log('parent clicked')">
  <div @click="console.log('child clicked')">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

If I run the app in the browser, and click on "Hello", both click handlers trigger and I see both logs in the console. If I do the same thing in Cypress, only the click on the child element triggers.

So what it seems like is that the event doesn't bubble upwards, as if `stopPropagation()` is called on the child event. But again, it only happens when I run Cypress.

I honestly have no idea how to approach solving this. Does anyone have any idea what this could be related to?

Ps: Not sure how much it matters, but I use Vite to run the app.